# Ubuntu - Weird brightness flickering

Tags: nvidia, brightness, 16.10

Today I uninstalled xubuntu and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10

As soon as it was all done, I entered the login menu. I noticed my screen was sort of flickering. I thought this would fix itself after I installed the newest Nvidia drivers. So from Additional Drivers I installed 367.57 and rebooted. After this didn't fix it, I installed 370.28. This also did not fix it.

I believe it's the brightness. I've seen a lot of people with the issue of "screen flickering", but from what I can tell those are usually different than my issue. For reference, here's a video of my screen both on my installation and using the live usb.

Installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWmROHKB1gY

Live USB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76RgN1YEat8

Speaking of youtube, I notice the flickering is not present when I have full screen video up, but it does affect the video while it's not in fullscreen

I'm at a loss. I really have no idea how to fix this, and google doesn't seem to have a solution. Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing?

I want to use Ubuntu, but I don't see how this is viable. If I can't fix this asap I'll have to back to xubuntu or try another distro.

I am using this laptop:
https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE70-2PE-Apache-Pro.html#hero-overview

**EDIT**

This issue is NOT present on 16.04 live cd.

**EDIT 2**

Upgraded kernel from `4.8.0` to `4.8.4` and no change

Downgraded kernel to `4.7.0` and no change

**EDIT 3**

I went all the way down to kernel version `4.4.27` which worked! I no longer have the flickering.

Anyone got a clue why it works now but not on the later kernel versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution that worked for me.

Run the command: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Here, edit the following from:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
To
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"`

Then run: `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

The issue apparently is with **Panel Self Refresh (psr)**

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your youtube video: I have what appears to be exactly the same problem on a Lenovo e540 equipped with dual boot ubuntu gnome 16.10/16.04. The problem does NOT seem to exist on 16.04 but it does on 16.10. My Lenovo has integrated Intel graphics Haswell Mobile on a Core i3-4100M.

Interestingly I also have a Clevo with Intel integrated graphics: Core i3-3110M with Ivybridge Mobile graphics running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 and on this computer the problem DOES NOT EXIST.

It looks like the graphics driver has to be updated to cope with certain changes in the kernel.

If someone more knowledgeable could explain why updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 causes problems on the same machine, I would be grateful. For example, is is a question of being patient until the graphics driver is updated for Haswell Mobile or should I invest in a Mac next time?

Comment: Just to make you aware that I posted an answer to my own question with the fix that worked for me